# Dynamic segmentation with respect to a control factor

Tags: arcpy, linear-referencing, dynamic-segmentation

Is there a way either with python scripts or other solution to dynamically segment a table with linear measures (from-to fields)
Each segmented section (from-to) should have all the item numbers written to a field that is within a certain range. 
e.g:

Input table

```
row1.  A-----c ===> itemID =1400
row2.  B-----F ===> itemID =1401
row3.  D-----F ===> itemID =1402
```

Output Table

```
row1.  A-----B ===> itemID =1400
row2.  B-----C ===> itemID =1400; 1401
row3.  C-----D ===> itemID =1401
row4.  D-----F ===> itemID =1401; 1402
```

[image]

Note: the input table is just a dbf file...

Comment: Welcome to the site Samuel.  I would recommend generating sample data in a table, taking a screenshot, and posting that.  The sample data should include the data and the intended output.

Comment: Item ID Begin  End  
1000 0 1  
1001 0 5  
1002 1 7  
1003 4 5  
1004 3 5  
    
Begin  End  Item ID Item ID
0 1  1000 1001
1 3  1001 1001; 1002
3 4  1002 1001; 1002; 1004
4 5  1003 1001; 1002; 1003; 1004
5 7  1004 1002

Comment: How about posting this as a jpeg to help with formatting?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/63uti4svk4k8oea/AABjvZICMC8MUCKXMTan9tQXa?dl=0

Comment: Great, this is helpful.  Now, you are looking to create a new field "Item" that contains all of the item ID's from the previous rows.  Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks Aaron...
Yes, i am looking to segment the ranges and for each segmented (without overlaps) range all the itemId associated to a range should be captured in a new field as shown in the picture.